# Finding $\min \sum_{k=-n}^nx_k ^2$ with constraint $\sum_{k=-n}^n x_k= 0$ and $\sum_{k=-n}^n kx_k=1$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

> Find $\min \{\sum_{k=-n}^nx_k^2\;|\;(x_{-n},\ldots, x_n)\in \mathbb R, \sum_{k=-n}^n x_k= 0 \text{ and } \sum_{k=-n}^n kx_k=1\}$

Here's my attempt.

There seems to be some inner product involved here, Cauchy-Schwarz might prove useful.

Let $\alpha$ be a real parameter, $u=(x_{-n},\ldots, x_n)$ and note that

$$||u||\cdot|| \alpha(1,\ldots,1)+(-n,\ldots, n)||\geq \langle u,\alpha(1,\ldots,1)+(-n,\ldots, n) \rangle =1$$

Hence $\displaystyle \sum_{k=-n}^nx_k^2 = ||u|| \geq \frac{1}{(2n+1)\alpha ^2 +\frac{n}{3}(2n^2+3n+1)}$ for every $\alpha \in \mathbb R$.

My idea is to then chose a convenient $\alpha$ where the equality is achieved. Such $\alpha$ must achieve equality in Cauchy- Schwarz inequality, that is to say we're looking for $\alpha, \lambda$ such that $u=\lambda [\alpha(1,\ldots,1)+(-n,\ldots, n)]$.

But summing the $2n+1$ equalities yields $0=\sum_{k=-n}^n x_k= \lambda\alpha  (2n+1)$.

Therefore, $\alpha=0$. Therefore the minimum we're looking for should be $\displaystyle\frac{3}{n(2n^2+3n+1)}$, which is achieved at $u=\displaystyle\frac{3}{n(2n^2+3n+1)}(-n,\dots, n)$

> Is my answer correct ? Is there a more straightforward way ? (A solution with Lagrange multipliers would be nice)

Comment: You are given $<f(k),1>=0$, $<f(k),k>=1$, hence $<f(k),f(k)>\ge \frac {<f(k),k>^2}{<k,k>}=<k^2,1>^{-1}$ which equality when $f(k)=\frac {k}{<k,k>}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide a solution based on Lagrange multipliers. So, we want to minimize
$$L=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{x_k^2}+\lambda_1\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{x_k}+\lambda_2\left(\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{kx_k}-1\right)$$
At the stationary points we have that
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_k}=2x_k+\lambda_1+k\lambda_2=0 \qquad(-n\leq k\leq n)\qquad (1)$$
Summing all $2n+1$ above equations we obtain
$$2\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{x_k}+(2n+1)\lambda_1+\lambda_2\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{k}=0$$
which in turn yields
$$\lambda_1=0$$
Multiplying (1) by $k$ and considering the sum over all $k$ we result
$$2\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{kx_k}+\lambda_2\sum_{k=-n}^{n}{k^2}=0$$
or equivalently
$$2+2\lambda_2\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k^2}=0$$
Thus
$$\lambda_2=-\frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$$
So the optimal points are obtained from (1) by replacing $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ i.e.
$$x_k=\frac{3k}{n(n+1)(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Thank you. I think some extra work is needed to state that a minimum is achieved at that point.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM You are welcome! The fact that the stationary point is a minimum follows from the positive definiteness of the Hessian $\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial x^2}=2I$.